# Is it possible to schedule running Mail.app rules?

Tags: macos, snow-leopard, mail.app

I have a number of rules in Mail.app (these ones work!) to move e-mails which are X days old to trash.

I'd like to run these rules at a specified time, eg: midnight. In this case, the particular rules will move e-mails which are older than 1 day to trash.

I use [Mail Act-On](http://indev.ca/MailActOn.html) and [Mail Tags](http://indev.ca/MailTags.html), but cannot find any functions there.

Is it possible with Mail.app natively? If not, is it possible with some plugin? Ideally open-source.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I would approach this - note it is quite technical and is recommended only to people who know what they are doing.

1) Write an Apple Script to send the keystroke to apply your defined rules in Mail.app

2) Schedule a crontab to run that script at predetermined times

To start you off here is a sample script that I have written:

```
tell application "System Events"
tell application "Mail" to activate
keystroke "l" using {command down, option down}
end tell
```

Then to schedule your job (e.g. midnight) by adding a crontab entry - change the username to the user you are running Mail.app as - leave osascript as it is

`* 0 * * * username osascript 'path to your script.scpt'`

Alternatively use a GUI to schedule the above such as cronnix http://code.google.com/p/cronnix/

Comment: Hi,

I like the approach. I hadn't thought about using applescript...

"keystroke "l" using {command down, option down}"

I guess this line is for the keystroke set-up in Mail Act-On to activate the particular defined rule?

If so, I follow.

I'll try it later on and let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not aware of running individual rules, the above shortcut will apply all rules that you have defined (as it is an existing Mail.app shortcut)

Comment: Juat to clarify:

"keystroke "l" using {command down, option down}"

This _'l'_ is an existing Mail.app shortcut to apply **ALL** rules?

thanks.

Comment: Yes as in Option+Command+L